# Console application that validates address

Tags: c#, google-maps, console-application

So I'm trying to figure out how to build a Console Application in C# that essentially mimics google maps. I need to be able to enter an address (even if I abbreviate a word. EX: Silverbell Dr) and output the correct spelling (Silverbell Drive).

The goal here is to be able to enter an address in the search, even if the address spelling is incorrect, and output a value that is close enough to the user input that it won't send back a null value.

If anyone has anything that is similar to this, I would greatly appreciate the help!

*Boss gave me this assignment knowing that I hardly have a base knowledge on the subject*

Comment: One way would be to use the Google API itself to give you this information. Otherwise you would need to store a big list of addresses in a database and use a search engine to find the words. You can look into ElasticSearch for that.

Comment: Google the term "Address normalization", that is the process you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it would be to use Googles geocode API. You can pass it a partial address and it will do it's best to return the normalized address for you. If the address isn't very specific, you will get back more than one.

Here's a code example for calling the API and parsing the results:

```
private static List<string> GetNormalizedAddresses(string address)
{
    // Generate request Uri
    var baseUrl = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml";
    var requestUri = $"{baseUrl}?address={Uri.EscapeDataString(address)}&sensor=false";

    // Get response
    var request = WebRequest.Create(requestUri);
    var response = request.GetResponse();
    var xDoc = XDocument.Load(response.GetResponseStream());
    var results = xDoc.Element("GeocodeResponse")?.Elements("result").ToList();

    var normalizedAddresses = new List<string>();

    // Populate results
    if (results != null)
    {
        normalizedAddresses.AddRange(results
            .Select(result => result.Element("formatted_address")?.Value)
            .Where(formattedAddress => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(formattedAddress)));
    }

    return normalizedAddresses;
}
```

Then, you could call it like so:

```
while(true)
{
    Console.Write("Enter a partial address: ");
    var partialAddress = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine(new string ('-', 25 + partialAddress.Length));

    var normalizedAddress = GetNormalizedAddresses(partialAddress);

    if (!normalizedAddress.Any())
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Sorry, couldn't find anything.");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("That address normalizes to:");
        Console.WriteLine($" - {string.Join($"\n - ", normalizedAddress)}");
    }

    Console.WriteLine("\n");        
}
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Wow, Rufus L! This is perfect! I've essentially learned how to read a few different coding languages, but haven't quite figured out how you magicians write this stuff! I really appreciate the help!